# How to set the value of a hidden input to the value of a function after it is called?

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a hidden input.

`<input type="hidden" id="gclid_field" name="gclid_field" value="">`

I need to grab the query string via the function below and pass that value to the input value.

```
function getParam(p) {
  var match = RegExp('[?&]' + p + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
  return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

I know this is pretty basic but I have not touched Javascript in a long time and can't seem to word the question correctly to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the input and set the `value`:

```
document.getElementById('gclid_field').value = getParam(p);
```